# unable to mount read-only DVD with photos

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd, read-only

I have a working Samsung CD/DVD player with (SATA connection) and i'm running latest updated version of 12.04. Audio CDs and video DVDs appear in the devices sidebar, but I have a DVD from a professional photographer with pictures of my daughter and friends which will just not open.

When I try to mount in terminal I get the following message:

```
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

mount: you must specify the file system type
```

I am assuming it's JPEG.

What should I do next?

I have looked through previous questions in this area but none seems to address this particular problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to mount in terminal I get the following message:
>
> ```
> mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
>
> mount: you must specify the filesystem type
> ```

You need to make extra sure you specify the filesystem type. It's not related to the fact it has JPEG images on it.

So, try mounting with:

```
sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

or

```
sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

if the first fails.

where `[/path/to/mount/point]` is a directory that exists and is empty. The reason this works is that we are specifying the FS type manually as the error message asks us to do.

However, the OP's `dmesg` had many entries such as:

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1248
```

which meant that the disk was corrupt or damaged,